# Site doesn't load in IE9 when using WP Minify wordpress plugin

Tags: internet-explorer-9, wordpress

I started using WP Minify last week, and it works perfect in all other browsers apart from IE9.

In IE9, only the background loads but nothing else. I can view the source and it all looks ok, but it's just a completely blank screen.

I've tried WP Minify only minifying JS, CSS and HTML individiually, but all three settings have the same issue.

Any ideas why this is?  My site is http://www.onedirection.net.

I've disabled the plugin for now.

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: I know you had to disable the plugin, but it's going to be impossible to help you without seeing the bug in action or the code that causes it. You can't expect us to run it through the minifier ourselves.

Comment: Hi, yes good point :)  I've just re-enabled it on a single page (the site uses caching so the other pages won't have time to update yet). Try this page now, I've just checked that it again fails in IE9 http://www.onedirection.net/bio/

Comment: Not a real answer but I advise to use W3 total cache, it has many caching options including a minify. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Comment: You're right, that's not a real answer. WP Super Cache has a large user-base and many use it in conjunction with WP Minify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right I've solved it.

It was to do with the order of js files in my code, particularly jQuery, but also a prettyPhoto reference.

A bit of moving some code around and everything is sorted!

So WP Super Cache is now working fine with WP Minify.

Comment: So rule of the day is to check all the JS errors in Chrome/IE console.